# How add assertion in Z3 of the form x=y^2

Tags: z3

I need to add the following assertion

assert(x=y^2)

is it required to define a function or any syntax is available to add it directly 
.Please help me.

Comment: How are you talking to Z3, i.e., which language, via text files or APIs?

Comment: @Christoph Wintersteiger Using python ,we can represent that as s.add(x==(y**2)).But how Z3 will internally represent that ?

Comment: Internally there is an exponentiation operator, similar to other arithmetical functions, such as +, *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z3 has a built-in power operator, `^`.  If you're using the SMT-LIB interface it would be `(assert (= x (^ y 2)))`. You'd probably be better off using `(assert (= x (* y y)))` if the power is always 2, though.